# add a datagridviewrow with buttons to the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to create a datagridview with 4 columns. The first column contains an edit button per row. The second contains a delete button and the next columns should contain the object data to display like ID, Firstname and so on.

For the buttons I use the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` for the other ones I use the `DataGridViewColumn`. When running the program I initialize the datagridview once after initializing the form.

When adding a new row I create the two buttons and try to fill these four columns.

So this is my code

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializePeopleList();
    }

    private void InitializePeopleList()
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn editButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

        DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

        DataGridViewColumn idColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
        idColumn.HeaderText = "ID";

        DataGridViewColumn firstNameColumn = new DataGridViewColumn();
        firstNameColumn.HeaderText = "FirstName";

        dgvPeople.Columns.Add(editButtonColumn);
        dgvPeople.Columns.Add(deleteButtonColumn);
        dgvPeople.Columns.Add(idColumn);
        dgvPeople.Columns.Add(firstNameColumn);
    }

    private void CreatePerson()
    {
        // open a new dialog, create a new Person object and add it to the data list

        AddPersonRow(newPerson); // Update GUI
    }

    private void AddPersonRow(Person newPerson)
    {
        DataGridViewRow personRow = new DataGridViewRow(); // Create a new row

        Button editButton = new Button(); // create a new edit button for the first column
        editButton.Text = "Edit";
        editButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => UpdatePersonFirstName(newPerson.ID, personRow.Cells[3]);

        Button deleteButton = new Button(); // create a new delete button for the second column
        editButton.Text = "Delete";
        editButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => RemovePerson(newPerson.ID, personRow);

        personRow.Cells[0].Value = editButton;
        personRow.Cells[1].Value = deleteButton;
        personRow.Cells[2].Value = newPerson.ID; // Display the ID in the third column
        personRow.Cells[3].Value = newPerson.FirstName; // Display the First Name in the fourth column

        dgvPeople.Rows.Add(personRow); // add this row to the datagridview
    }

    private void RemovePerson(Guid personId, DataGridViewRow personRow)
    {
            // Remove the person from the data list

            dgvPeople.Rows.Remove(personRow); // Update GUI
    }

    private void UpdatePersonFirstName(Guid personId, DataGridViewCell firstNameCell)
    {
        // open a new dialog and edit the Person

        // update the person in the data list

        firstNameCell.Value = updatedFirstName;
    }
}
```

When I run the program the code crashes when I try to add a new person to the datagridview at `AddPersonRow` at

`personRow.Cells[0].Value`

I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because `personRow.Cells` has a `Count` of 0.

How can I add a new row to the datagridview that has two button columns and two text columns?

Comment: Use a panel and put buttons and columns into the panel.  It will look like the DGV row.  With you code it is easier to put people into a datatable and then make the datatable the source of the DGV.  Lot easier.

Comment: `new DataGridViewRow()` creates empty row without columns. So firstly add row to grid, then set cell values.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov then I get a `InvalidOperationException` because at least one item has no cell template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization:

```
var editButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
editButtonColumn.Text = "Edit";
editButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

var deleteButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
deleteButtonColumn.Text = "Delete";
deleteButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

var idColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
idColumn.HeaderText = "ID";

var firstNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
firstNameColumn.HeaderText = "FirstName";

dgvPeople.Columns.Add(editButtonColumn);
dgvPeople.Columns.Add(deleteButtonColumn);
dgvPeople.Columns.Add(idColumn);
dgvPeople.Columns.Add(firstNameColumn);

dgvPeople.CellContentClick += DgvPeople_CellContentClick;
```

No need to create buttons. They will be created automatically because `DataGridViewButtonColumn` is used.

```
private void AddPersonRow(Person newPerson)
{
    var rowIndex = dgvPeople.Rows.Add();
    var row = dgvPeople.Rows[rowIndex];
    row.Cells[2].Value = newPerson.ID;
    row.Cells[3].Value = newPerson.FirstName;
}
```

Here we react to button presses:

```
private void DgvPeople_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0) // exclude header
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            // edit action                    
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            // delete action
            //dgvPeople.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```